# Move_base: cannot cancel while executing recovery behavior

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I'm using move_base action client to send goals to my robot and cancel if necessary. It works fine, but I have realized that cancelGoal doesn't work while executing recovery behavior. That is, if I call cancelGoal or cancelAllGoals, the subsequent call to waitForResult doesn't return until all recovery fails. I have tried to disable recovery behavior with:

> rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam set move_base recovery_behavior_enabled false

Again, this doesn't returns until recovery fails (more than 2 minutes!). I suppose move_base gets somehow blocked when running recovery behavior and don't even attend reconfigure requests.

Btw, I'm using hydro-devel code navigation stack, but experienced the same with groovy package installation.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61720/move_base:-cannot-cancel-while-executing-recovery-behavior/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2013-04-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) on 2016-03-25**:
me have the same issue either . need to repeatly send  the cancel command to stop robot from rotating around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like a bug.

Why not [open a defect ticket](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues)?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-02**:
You are right;  ticket #34

**Comment by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) on 2016-11-13**:
Hello from 2016, Is this problem solved ?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2016-11-14**:
Unfortunately no. A PR would be more than welcome

**Comment by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) on 2016-11-15**:
Alright, it may takes a while to learn the nav stack from under the hood T_T.
If i can archive it, i will do that PR.  :D